# Почему не мапится сервлет?

Tags: java, servlet

У меня сервлет `AddUserServlet`:

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String name = req.getParameter("name");
        final String login = req.getParameter("login");
        final String email = req.getParameter("email");

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(login);
        System.out.println(email);
    }
}
```

Это мой `web.xml`:

```
<!--root menu, index.jsp-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.UserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--Вот этот не мапится.-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.AddUserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Находясь по аддресу `http://localhost:8080/items/addition.jsp` я получаю `addition.jsp` страницу:

```
<body>  
    <form method="post" action="AddUserServlet">

        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" name="login"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить">

    </form>
</body>
```

Но при отправке формы получаю `HTTP Status [405] – [Method Not Allowed]` вместо моих входящих значений.

Но когда я `<url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>` меняю на `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` то все работает. Но у меня к корню примапен другой сервлет и он мне нужен.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне примапить еще и `AddUserServlet` так чтобы он работал с `addition.jsp` и получал данные от него? Буду очень признателен за любые подсказки...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите в `form` в `action` URL, а не имя сервлета.

```
<body>  
    <form method="post" action="addition">

        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" name="login"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить">

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: нет это не работает. Я нашел, там наоборот надо было в мапинге имя сервлета указать `<url-pattern>/AddUserServlet</url-pattern>`. Так работает.

Comment: вам надо было исправить либо `action`, либо `mapping`. оба варианта сработают.

Comment: я честно попробовал как-только вы это написали не помогло, получил вот это:`HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Type Status Report

Message /addition`

Comment: может быть для вашего варианта надо что-то еще поменять?

Comment: надо убрать `/`. я исправил пример.

Comment: Ой пардон не с той вкладки ошибку написал извините, вот какая реакция получается когда в форме я параметром `action="/addition"` и в `web.xml <url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>` то выходит `HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Type Status Report

Message /addition` получается форме надо знать с каким сервлетом она работает, или возможно это нужно указать как-то еще помимо параметра `action`.

Comment: поэтому я и убрал `/`. что бы URL стал относительный.

Comment: все до меня дошло и заработало спасибо большое. Я правильно понял что в моем варианте мы в xml указываем сервлет, а с вашим так получается что путь к конкретному файлу так как жестко определили путь через `<url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>` и никакой другой файл кроме `addition.jsp` использовать этот сервлет не сможет?

Comment: в `action` указывается URL. в **web.xml** вы указывает какой сервлет отвечает на заданный URL. URL без начального `/` относительный, то есть полный URL будет учитывать текущее положение.

Comment: тоесть в web.xml я один раз объявляю существование сервлета в `<servlet></servlet>` а потом маплю в нем-же любое количество страниц с помощью блоков `<servlet-mapping>` указывая одинаковый `<servlet-name>`. А `<url-pattern>` будет у каждого свой но путь указывается абсолютный от `/`, где `/` это корень папки `webapp`. А у формы указывается относительный от того места откуда произошло отправление запроса поэтому он без `/` и всегда будет просто совпадать и именем файла. Правильно или что-нибудь напутал?